# How to enqueue admin content outside admincp

Tags: admin, wp-enqueue-script

How do I enqueue admin javascript/css/header outside admincp, and specifically outside Wordpress.

I checked one of the admin pages, and it contains this line:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php' );
```

I tried it, but it didn't work.

I want to use it besides:

```
require_once('wp-load.php');
```